# Type missmatch error in formik errors using typescript

Tags: typescript, formik, react-i18next

I have custom component for inputs for `formik` and inside of it I render error label if exist.
If I print it like: `{errors[field.name]}` it works
But {t(errors[field.name]?.toLocaleString())} this doesnt.

```
import { FieldProps, FormikErrors } from "formik";
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";

const InputField: React.FC<InputFieldProps & FieldProps> = ({
  field,
  form: { touched, errors },
  type,
  label,
  ...props
}) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  
  return (
    <div>
      <label
        htmlFor={field.name}>
        {label}
      </label>
      <input
        type={type}
        {...field}
        {...props}/>
      {touched[field.name] && errors[field.name] && (
        <div>
          <p>
            {errors[field.name]}
            {t(errors[field.name])} <---- this does not work
          </p>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default InputField;
```

I am getting error:

```
Argument of type 'string | FormikErrors<any> | string[] | FormikErrors<any>[] | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TemplateStringsArray | Normalize<{test: 'test'}> | (TemplateStringsArray | Normalize<...>)[]'.
```

Comment: Can you show how you're rendering `InputField`? It'd be helpful to know where everything is coming from

Comment: please share `InputFieldProps` type

Answer (score 3):

This is how I resolved it. I was getting same error in formik with mui library:

```
 {errors?.fieldName && typeof errors.fieldName=== "string" && (
                    <Typography component={'div'} fontSize={12} color={'red'}>
                      {errors.fieldName}
                    </Typography>)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Got this issue with `useFormik()`, and I was able to safely cast the error as such

```
{formik.errors.fieldName ? <div>{formik.errors.fieldName as string}</div> : null}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `?` inside `errors[field.name]?.toLocaleString()` means: "return `undefined` if the property `toLocaleString` doesn't exist on `errors[field.name]`". Then it tries passing `undefined` into `t()`, which falls outside its definition and is why you see error  .

However, you probably don't need optional chaining because 4 lines above it you are already checking for the property `[field.name]`.

Removing the `?` should fix it. Try `t(errors[field.name].toLocaleString())` and let me know if it works.

Comment: Actually I just forgot to remove '?' here in question I get same error without it

Comment: Ok, the problem still relates to the function t() -  you are allowing a type to be passed into it that doesn’t match its  interface. Make sure that you’re passing a string into it and you should be fine.

Comment: I know it should be string passed in to t() function. It's react-18next library but this errors[x] is not string. I don't know how to cast it or set in a way that it work.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `typeof errors[field.name] === 'string'` to assure typescript that it is a string.

```js
import React from 'react'
import { FieldProps, FormikErrors } from "formik";
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";

type InputFieldProps = any
const InputField: React.FC<InputFieldProps & FieldProps> = ({
  field,
  form: { touched, errors },
  type,
  label,
  ...props
}) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  return (
    <div>
      <label
        htmlFor={field.name}>
        {label}
      </label>
      <input
        type={type}
        {...field}
        {...props} />
      {touched[field.name] && typeof errors[field.name] === 'string' && (
        <div>
          <p>
            {errors[field.name]}
            {t(errors[field.name])}
          </p>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default InputField;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChRJY4BvOAMWCQBsATABRzAGcAae6EMADWAUSg4oXOAF842XHABEmAcMUBucuGjxaAVy5IAKlBQA7LkxQxgEMzLk48iouhgBaYAEYAHGaQAHjAapKQwAJ5gSHAAkmZgejAMzOycUgC8cObhpGh2XPBxCUmMrABciMQwAHR0AMIAPEWJyawcENxwAGT0pakdXAB8cJkAFNSkcHJ9PJNyAhW0MBB6aAAWSCx8SOLQUtKzUxFRh3BWAEbMp9U3YGmk0gCUI8MTU3kWunDwspkGxqYLFYbHZRo9NHMiDA9FB7KM5lMGixgAA3QYIqZwBoXZgYzFwNYwEBMOjQdLUTB9apmFAgJDSdH4-HUHFMaR4rEAelZjKZDWA8USHKOkSQ5OO9OFNBu1UpKXZTMx1BldwGsk5vOZy1WGxYAG05axqbSkABdbo9CUQTBwHYSLgGqk0unm9JuggFKACgDm%20AtcHhisRyLRUsRYE1Qam1Dte0dKWNLoVUaVMFGsck8aNzrNj2TUYanIjUsLIcjUzzGNLqN54IeEMClHgLCQmBQeiYhUFJRS6iAA)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of handling this typescript error .

We can use `as string` or `String(errors.email)` like this :

```js
  {errors?.email && touched?.email && (
        <div className="text-red-500 mt-3">
             {errors?.email as string}
        </div>
  )}
```

```js
  {errors?.email && touched?.email && (
        <div className="text-red-500 mt-3">
             {String(errors?.email)}
        </div>
  )}
```

Or we can use the `<ErrorMessage />` component from formik :

```js
   import { ErrorMessage } from 'formik';

   <ErrorMessage name="email" />
```